# Labelled images but don't know what those labels correspond to

Tags: python, image, image-processing, machine-learning

I have a bunch of images (basically a resized subset of Celeba dataset). And I have a binary label for each of those images. The images are people's faces.

The problem is : I don't know to which characteristic correspond those labels.

Do you have any method to "backtest" features and labels ? I have no idea how to determine what those labels correspond to.

I have tried visualizing those images again and again trying to understand what were the similarities between the images without success.

I have tried SVM classifier and then plot the coefficients to determine where the classifier was targeted, without success.

Thank you for the help

Comment: If you trained a classifer, you had to tell it what features to use and what labels to use in training. Then your prediction is based on those features and targets. It's not clear from your question what you aren't sure about. Perhaps you can provide a sample of the data that is confusing you?

Comment: The dataset is pretty simples : 80k faces, each associated to a 0 or a 1 and I have no idea what are those labels are related to on the image (mustache? skin color? sex?...).

Comment: According to a [kaggle page](https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/celeba-dataset) for the dataset, there should be "Attribute labels for each image. There are 40 attributes" included with the dataset. I would advise you go back and look at where you got the data, as they may have pre-selected a target. In general, the _first_ step in a machine learning or data science project should be to design the experiment based on a hypothesis, not to start fitting models to data. This step can help you avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

No.  From an information theory standpoint, there is no way to reconstruct an arbitrary, abstract concept from a set of observations.  This is equivalent to most research using the scientific method: you're trying to guess the classification rationale from a finite set of data.  A guess that does a reliable job of predicting observed behaviour is called a "theory".

Does that help frame the way you look at the problem you're facing?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So from what you said my problem is now a bit different. First, I try to classify my images based on an assumption. Second, I check back if my initial labels correspond to my theory. What would you advise as for feature extraction from scratch on faces ?